# MySQL select with variable not working

Tags: php, mysql, select

```
$select = "SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE location ='".$loc."' ";
$findname = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
```

I keep getting this error!  I have tried everything!!!

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE location ='Florida'' at line 1

$loc is determined by the following:

```
<input type="text" name="loc"> in the HTML
$loc = $_POST['loc']; in the PHP
```

Comment: Seems to me like something is wrong with your $loc, can you show the example of the variable? Seems to me the variable ' is escaping and makes your statement to be SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE ='' (2x single quoted) Florida'

Comment: The variable is just from a post field where you enter Florida.  Simply $location = $_POST['location']; @Sky

Comment: @user3430837 try using like keyword

Answer (score 1):

Try this , use `mysql_escape_string` or `mysql_real_escape_string` mysql safe string functions

```
$select = "SELECT `name` FROM `table_name` WHERE `location` ='".mysql_escape_string($loc)."' ";
$findname = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: your problem is in `table_name` make sure you have added correct table name

Answer (score 0):

```
$select = "SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE location ='".mysql_real_escape_string($loc)."' ";
$findname = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: This gives me: ...right syntax to use near 'WHERE location ='Florida'' … same error @SajithNair

Answer (score 0):

Just check for any `single quotes or double quotes` in the location variable. That might be a problem.

Use `str_replace(find,replace,string)` to replace single and double quotes in the string.

Example, when you can contain a double quote in the `$loc` variable.

`$select = "SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE location ='Flo"rida' ";`

The query will end at `Flo`.

Comment: There is no single quote or double quote in my input string for location.

Comment: try using `"SELECT table_name.name FROM table_name WHERE table_name.location ='".$loc."' ";`

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_real_escape_string` after `WHERE location =`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.  I was using a variable for the table name and was referencing a null value.  Thanks for the help!